# Select dropdown not expanding to full on first click

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

We trying to populate drop down values on click of dropdown itself. But when we get response back from sever select is not opening fully just showing sect as first option and then first item in option.
 But for second click it's opening properly.

[image: First Click]

[image: Second click]

Following is my html code

```html
<select class="form-control" id="sessionGroupLevel2{{$index}}" 
        name="sessionGroupLevel2" 
        ng-model="sap.sessionGroupLevel2Id" 
        ng-disabled="sap.checkboxValue!=true?(sap.group!=1?sap.group!=1:sap.group==1):sap.group!=1" 
        ng-options="grp2.id as grp2.label for grp2 in sessiongrp2list{{$index}}" 
        ng-click="changeGrouplevel2Result(sap.sessionGroupLevel1,sap.sessionGroupLevel2Id,$index)">
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

Please guide my what wrong I am doing here

Regards
Mahesh

Comment: Can you give an example of a jsfiddle that would reproduce the problem?

Comment: We fixed this issue by removing on-click event from drop-down and populating option list through another event